# Cleveref doesn't find the label

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, mdframed, cleveref

The following code gives me as reference the section and not the signpost. It is probably a beginner's mistake.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mdframed}


\newcounter{signpost}%
\newenvironment{signpost}[1][]{%
    \stepcounter{signpost}%
        \ifstrempty{#1}%
        {\mdfsetup{%
            frametitle={%
                \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
                \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
                {\strut Summary~\thesignpost};}}
        }%
        {\mdfsetup{%
            frametitle={%
                \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
                \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
                {\strut Summary~\thesignpost:~#1};}}%
        }%
        \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
            linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
            skipabove=6pt, skipbelow=6pt, nobreak=true,
            frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
        \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
        }{\end{mdframed}}

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{signpost}{summary}{summaries} 



\begin{document}

\section{Hello Stackexchange}

This is some text.

\begin{signpost}[This is a summary]
This is a summary of the above text.
\label{signpost:MWE}
\end{signpost}

In \cref{signpost:MWE} you see \ldots

\end{document}
```

What do I need to change in order to get the "In signpost 1 you see..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change `\stepcounter{signpost}` to `\refstepcounter{signpost}`. The latter makes your `signpost` counter the one used by the reference mechanism.