# including chapters in mdframed references

Tags: mdframed, cleveref

I'd like to have chapter.theorem numbers for an `mdframed` theorem environment.  I can modify the environment definition to include this, as in:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{cleveref}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcounter{Theorem}[chapter]
\newenvironment{Theorem}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{Theorem}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[line width=1pt,anchor=east,rectangle,draw=DarkOliveGreen,fill=white]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Theorem}~\thechapter.\theTheorem};}}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[line width=1pt,anchor=east,rectangle,draw=DarkOliveGreen,fill=white]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Theorem}~\thechapter.\theTheorem:~\color{Maroon}{#1}};}}%
  }%
  \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=DarkOliveGreen,%
            linewidth=1pt,topline=true,%
            frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
  \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
  }{\end{mdframed}}

\crefname{Theorem}{theorem}{theorems} 
\Crefname{Theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{blah}

\begin{Theorem}[Distribution of inner products]\label{thm:stokesTheoremGeometricAlgebraII:1420}
Given two blades $A_s, B_r$ with grades subject to $0 < r < s$, and a vector $b$, the inner product distributes according to
\begin{equation*}
    A_s \cdot \left( b \wedge B_r \right) = \left( A_s \cdot b \right) \cdot B_r.
\end{equation*}
\end{Theorem}

Reference to \cref{thm:stokesTheoremGeometricAlgebraII:1420}.

\end{document}
```

To get cleveref to find the label, this was modified to use `refstepcounter` instead of `stepcounter` as shown in [cleveref-doesnt-find-the-label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125308/cleveref-doesnt-find-the-label).  This produces:

[image: cref to fix]

How can I modify things so that the cref output shows up as 'theorem 1.1' (i.e. including the chapter number as in the theorem title text)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already loading `amsmath`, you can say

```
\newcounter{Theorem}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{chapter}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{cleveref}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcounter{Theorem}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{chapter}
\newenvironment{Theorem}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{Theorem}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[line width=1pt,anchor=east,rectangle,draw=DarkOliveGreen,fill=white]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Theorem}~\theTheorem};}}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[line width=1pt,anchor=east,rectangle,draw=DarkOliveGreen,fill=white]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Theorem}~\theTheorem:~\color{Maroon}{#1}};}}%
  }%
  \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=DarkOliveGreen,%
            linewidth=1pt,topline=true,%
            frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
  \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
  }{\end{mdframed}}

\crefname{Theorem}{theorem}{theorems} 
\Crefname{Theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{blah}

\begin{Theorem}[Distribution of inner products]\label{thm:stokesTheoremGeometricAlgebraII:1420}
Given two blades $A_s, B_r$ with grades subject to $0 < r < s$, and a vector $b$, the inner product distributes according to
\begin{equation*}
    A_s \cdot \left( b \wedge B_r \right) = \left( A_s \cdot b \right) \cdot B_r.
\end{equation*}
\end{Theorem}

Reference to \cref{thm:stokesTheoremGeometricAlgebraII:1420}.

\end{document}
```

[image]